# How to Implement Multiplication of Objects with Numpy Arrays from the Left Hand Side?

Tags: python, numpy

If one wants to multiply an arbitrary object from the left hand side with a `np.ndarray`, one gets into a problem.

The problem is, that `numpy.ndarray.__mul__` calls the right hand sides' `__rmul__` element-wise if the right hand side is a so far unknown type.

To see the problem, you can copy paste the following code and run it from the command line or a SDK. You can step with the debugger through it. Comments help you and guide you through it ...

```
import numpy as np


class Zora(object):

    def __init__(self, array):
        self._array = array
        self._values_field_name = array.dtype.names[-1]

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self._array

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self._array)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        result = self.copy()
        result *= other
        return result

    def __imul__(self, other):
        self._array[self._values_field_name] *= other
        return self

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        return self * other

    def copy(self):
        return self.__class__(self.a.copy())

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, fields, codes, data):
        array = np.array([(*c, d) for c, d in zip(codes, data)], dtype=fields)
        return cls(array)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Let's create a Zora dataset with  scenarios
    scenarios = 7

    fields = np.dtype([('LegalEntity', np.unicode_, 32), ('Division', np.unicode_, 32),
                       ('Scenarios', np.float64, (scenarios, ))])

    legal_entities = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C']
    divisions = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b']

    codes = list(zip(legal_entities, divisions))

    data = np.random.uniform(0., 1., (len(codes), scenarios))

    zora = Zora.create(fields, codes, data)

    # The dataset looks like the following
    print(zora)

    # We can multiply it from the left with scalars ...
    z = zora * 2
    print(zora * 2)

    # ... and with column vectors, for example ...
    # ... for this we generate a columns vector with some weights ...
    numrows = zora.a.shape[0]

    weights = np.expand_dims(np.array(list(range(numrows))), 1)
    # ... the weights ...
    print(weights)

    # ... left side multiplication works fine too with this
    print(zora * weights)

    # Let's show inplace multiplication ...
    # Which we apply on a copy, so that we can still compare ...
    z = zora.copy()
    z *= 2

    # Is pretty fine too, ...
    print(zora)
    print(z)

    # Now it becomes a bit special ...
    # ... when multiplying from the left.
    # It works fine with a scalar..
    z = 2 * zora
    print(z)

    # But becomes special with np.ndarrays ...
    print('-------------------------------------')
    print('-------------------------------------')
    print('The following result ...')
    z = weights * zora
    print(z)

    # which is not the same, but should, as ...
    print('-------------------------------------')
    print('... should be the same as this one ...')

    z = zora * weights
    print(z)

    # We got a list of arrays, where for each i-th array
    # the corresponding i-th weight has been used for
    # multiplication
    #
    # This has to do with numpy's implementation of calling
    # __rmul__ from the right hand side within the __mul__
    # from the np.ndarray ...
    #
    # The same is true for all other __r{...}__ methods
```

Answer (score 2):

### Use Numpy Hook `__array_ufunc__`

Numpy allows you to circumvent this problem by properly defining a `__array_ufunc__` method on your object.

The following method added to the `Zora` class above, does the job. It is easy to generalize it for all binary `ufunc`tions, including non commutative operations too. But I show this one only, not to make things to complicated.

```
def __array_ufunc__(self, ufunc, method, *inputs, **kwargs):
    lhs, rhs = inputs
    return rhs * lhs
```

Hence, the following will show the expected results ...

```
import numpy as np


class Zora(object):

    def __init__(self, array):
        self._array = array
        self._values_field_name = array.dtype.names[-1]

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self._array

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self._array)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        result = self.copy()
        result *= other
        return result

    def __imul__(self, other):
        self._array[self._values_field_name] *= other
        return self

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        return self * other

    def copy(self):
        return self.__class__(self.a.copy())

    def __array_ufunc__(self, ufunc, method, *inputs, **kwargs):
        lhs, rhs = inputs
        return rhs * lhs

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, fields, codes, data):
        array = np.array([(*c, d) for c, d in zip(codes, data)], dtype=fields)
        return cls(array)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Let's create a Zora dataset with  scenarios
    scenarios = 7

    fields = np.dtype([('LegalEntity', np.unicode_, 32), ('Division', np.unicode_, 32),
                       ('Scenarios', np.float64, (scenarios, ))])

    legal_entities = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C']
    divisions = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b']

    codes = list(zip(legal_entities, divisions))

    data = np.random.uniform(0., 1., (len(codes), scenarios))

    zora = Zora.create(fields, codes, data)

    # The dataset looks like the following
    print(zora)

    # We can multiply it from the left with scalars ...
    z = zora * 2
    print(zora * 2)

    # ... and with column vectors, for example ...
    # ... for this we generate a columns vector with some weights ...
    numrows = zora.a.shape[0]

    weights = np.expand_dims(np.array(list(range(numrows))), 1)
    # ... the weights ...
    print(weights)

    # ... left side multiplication works fine too with this
    print(zora * weights)

    # Let's show inplace multiplication ...
    # Which we apply on a copy, so that we can still compare ...
    z = zora.copy()
    z *= 2

    # Is pretty fine too, ...
    print(zora)
    print(z)

    # Now it becomes a bit special ...
    # ... when multiplying from the left.
    # It works fine with a scalar..
    z = 2 * zora
    print(z)

    # But becomes special with np.ndarrays ...
    print('-------------------------------------')
    print('-------------------------------------')
    print('The following result ...')
    z = weights * zora
    print(z)

    # which is now the same ...
    print('-------------------------------------')
    print('... should be the same as this one ...')

    z = zora * weights
    print(z)
```